# Australian Interstate Flight with US Drivers License Only - No Passport

Tags: air-travel, passports, australia, driving-licenses, virgin-australia

My husband and I booked tickets on Virgin Australia from Sydney to Perth and I'm wondering if I'll be okay to pass through security and check in using only my US Driver's License.

I ask because I  notice that the flight is a "Virgin Australia International Flight" despite it being only from Sydney to Perth. The name on my passport is still my maiden name (which is how I booked all my international flights), however this interstate flight was booked using my *married* name, which is what appears on my drivers license and all of my credit cards.

I had intended to update the name on my international flights (from my maiden name to my married name) once the name change paperwork was finalized, however when I called to  make the change United suggested it I leave it as is to avoid any issues (since the flight involves multiple legs and some alliance airlines.) At this point though, I had already booked the interstate flight using my new married name.

I can update my name with Virgin Australia but it'll cost more than what I paid for the ticket originally so, if possible, I'd rather leave it as is. I was planning on bringing a photocopy of my marriage license so, if needed, I could show why my passport name doesn't match all of my other forms of ID.

Comment: Where did you see this flight described as "international"?

Comment: And to clarify, you do actually have a valid passport in your possession - it's just that it has your maiden name?  Saying "no passport" in the title makes it sound like you don't have a passport at all, and might distract from the question of whether you could use your passport together with proof of your name change.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's likely one of those international flights with a domestic stopover, which requires clearing immigration at both Australian airports.

Comment: The flight is described as "Virgin Australia International Flight 555" in the booking confirmation. The issue is that the name on my passport doesn't match the name I booked this flight with (see above.) Hope that helps!

Comment: The **name of the airline** is (or has at some point been) "Virgin Australia International Airlines", even if some of their _flights_ may not be international.

Comment: VA 555 is a domestic flight departing from SYD Terminal 2 (domestic terminal).  There are no ID requirements on this flight.

Answer (score 3):

For a domestic flight (even this one that is marked as Virgin Australia International - it is a misnomer) you will basically have no issues.

You can usually check in at a kiosk and get your boarding pass then proceed to baggage drop.
They will likely pay little to no attention for married vs maiden name when you drop off your bag. If there is any issue then you state that you'll be carrying documentation proving the difference in name.

We also don't have TSA where there is ID check before security.
Don't stress too much about it and hope you have a great flight!

Comment: Note that some "domestic" flights in Australia are actually tag-ons of longer international ones, operating from the international terminal. Rules for these are different!

Comment: Absolutely they are, but they are few and far between. To my knowledge Virgin Australia operates no such flights, nor does Qantas. Only Jetstar on a very limited basis.